# Subversion on apache using proxy

Tags: proxy, svn

- I have a subversion server implemented as an Apache 2.0 server under Linux (RedHat).
- I have to access this server from Windows XP via a proxy.

If I try to connect with a browser under HTTPS I will be asked for `account/password` and every thing works fine.

If I try to access it with tortoise, I will be asked for account and password too, **but** then the connection failed.

If I disable authorization the connection **works**. If I am not using a proxy everything works fine.

Can some gave me a hint?

Answer (score 3):

It seems there is an issue with TortoiseSVN accessing your repository. Try to [configure proxy for TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-network), if you haven't already.